# Hide Anchor based on Text

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

```html
 <table class="k-tree-table">
 <tbody>
 <tr><td class="fixedCell" cellGroup="SH"><a class="specialButton" cellGroup="RI">SH</a></TD></tr>
 <tr><td class="fixedCell" cellGroup="RI"><a class="specialButton" cellGroup="RI">EP</a></TD></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to hide the anchor tag that contains the text 'SH'. I attempted the following but it fails to hide the anchor:

```
$("a.specialButton:contains('SH')").hide();
```

How can I get to this anchor tag and hide it using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the code does work as intended.

There are two reasons I can think of that would explain why this does not work for you:

1) You are not waiting for the DOM to be loaded before trying to hide the links.
As mentioned, be sure to wait by running this on the DOM ready event which can be written like such:

```
 $(function() {
    $('a.specialButton:contains("SH")').hide();
});
```

2) Perhaps your table is getting populated from some AJAX call.  If this is the case, then you need to run this function every time after the table is populated. Also, it would probably be a good idea to save a reference to the table and filter through just the table, and not your entire page.  This will help performance.

```
var $table = $('table.k-tree-table');

// This would be your callback for the AJAX to populate the table
function gotDataForTreeTable(data) {
    // your code for populating table goes here

    $table.find('a.specialButton:contains("SH")').hide();
}
```

I hope this helps and good luck.

Edit: Thanks for marking the answer correct. I am not sure what your conditions are for hiding the link, but it also dawned on me today that you could perhaps use CSS without needing additional Javascript.

```
td[cellGroup="SH"] a.specialButton { 
    display:none; 
}
```

Comment: It turns out there was a bit of javascript that was erroring just prior to the snippet in question. Once I moved the snippet above this piece of code it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does actually work. Make sure you are running the `jQuery` code only after the DOM is ready:

```js
$(function() {
    $('a.specialButton:contains("SH")').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="k-tree-table">
 <tbody>
 <tr><td class="fixedCell" cellGroup="SH"><a class="specialButton" cellGroup="RI">SH</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="fixedCell" cellGroup="RI"><a class="specialButton" cellGroup="RI">EP</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.specialButton:contains("SH")').hide();
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to avoid your answer being deleted as low-quality